# AngularJS: how to implement records per page using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need the following format "records per page" at the bottom of a table

Per page: 10 25 50

If we click on 10 it should show only 10 items and so on...also need to change the color of active selection

can any body help me! I am new to angularjs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `limitTo` in the `ng-repeat` expression for the filtering, and `ng-class` for changing the active class. I made a quick example here:

http://jsbin.com/aQipimU/2/edit

Comment: thanks much!! Is there any way to use dynamic template from directives for the same.